Differentiation in J
I am a beginner learning J based on this book (2015 version). I was able to run all examples until this one from the calculus chapter:
   ^&3  d. 1
3&*@(^&2)

I get this error locally:
|spelling error (invalid inflection)
|   ^&3 d. 1
|       ^

Can someone share the correct way to compute this derivative in J?
I run the following J version:
   9!:14 ''
j9.5.2/j64arm/darwin/commercial/www.jsoftware.com/2024-02-02T18:38:04/clang-14-0-0/SLEEF=1

and get a similar error in J Playground.

From Obsolete Syntax:

Support for calculus (d. D. D:) - the functions of these primitives are provided by the math/calculus addon

You can read more, including the reasoning for the removal of the primitives, at Addons/math/calculus.
You have to install 'math/calculus', though I think on the playground you need to use the github link instead:
install'github:jsoftware/math_calculus'
require'math/calculus'
^&3 deriv_jcalculus_ 1


Or use an earlier version of J - e.g. J807,Win 64 platform. All the exercises in the book version for Calculus will run smoothly without such error messages.
